# Observable on AngularJS does not interpolate: " cant find property of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, typescript, data-binding, interpolation, observable

everyone. I have an application that shows cats. It simply gets the data from a JSON using a service and http. This much I can do, and it works. However, I have another feature which is a "cat detail" page, that involves routing. It uses the same service but it does not render the whole JSON file, but only a particular object, in this case, a particular cat. I search for said  particular cat using a find() method over the first getcat()  function, using a route.params value as a search parameter.

However, routing isn't the problem itself. As you can see below. My console can print the return of the get function and shows properly the sole object it should . The problem seems to concern the moment of interpolation. When I bind the  variable, from the component to the template, that should carry the data of the observable, Angular shows me a "Cannot read property 'Nombre' of undefined".

I really don't know why this isn't working.  Some people recommend using the safe navigation operator on the binding, but that doesn't do it for me. The same error keeps appearing.

I have rechecked the syntax various days, and i do belief i got it right. This makes me think the problem relies on something that has to do with the scope of the component, maybe related to lifecycle hooks.

Any help will be much appreciated.

#### This is my JSON

```
[
  {
    "Nombre": "Xiomara",
    "Edad": "1",
    "Raza": "Criolla",
    "Color": "Café",
    "Vacunacion": "Todas",
    "Estado": "Esperando",
    "Foto" :"-104827/"
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Deneb",
    "Edad": "4",
    "Raza": "Siamés",
    "Color": "Negro",
    "Vacunacion": "Falta",
    "Estado": "Esperando",
    "Foto" : ""
  {
    "Nombre": "Pilatos",
    "Edad": "2",
    "Raza": "Dragoon",
    "Color": "Pardo",
    "Vacunacion": "Azul",
    "Estado": "Todas",
    "Foto" : ""
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Ulysses",
    "Edad": "1",
    "Raza": "Criollo",
    "Color": "Gris",
    "Vacunacion": "Falta",
    "Estado": "Esperando",
    "Foto" : "rt-fur-cat-104827/"
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Raiku",
    "Edad": "1",
    "Raza": "Pokemon",
    "Color": "Rayas blancas",
    "Vacunacion": "Todas",
    "Estado": "Esperando",
    "Foto" : "http-white-short-fur-cat-104827/"
  }
]
```

#### This is my service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class GatosService {
  private _productUrl ='./Lista Gatos.json';

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getGatos(): Observable<IGato[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
      .map((response: Response) => <IGato[]>response.json())
      .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  /* Searches array objects to match the id*/
  getGato(id: string): Observable<IGato> {
    return this.getGatos()
      .map((gatos: IGato[]) => gatos.find(p => p.Nombre === id))
      .do(data => console.log('Gato individual: ' + JSON.stringify(data))); 
    /*prints individual object on console. It does work */
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
   console.error(error);
   return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

#### This is my detailComponent.ts

```
export class GatoDetalleComponent implements OnInit {
  pageTitle: string = 'gato detalle';
  gato: IGato;
  errorMessage: string;
  private sub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private _route:ActivatedRoute,
    private _gatosService: GatosService
  ) {
    console.log(this._route.snapshot.params['id']) /* prints id so i know it works */
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    /* Calls the service function using the route.params as argument */
    this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        let id = params['id'];
        this.getGato(id);
      }
    )
  }
  /* Subscribes to the service getGato function and assigns it to variable gato*/
  getGato(id: string) {
    this._gatosService.getGato(id).subscribe(
      product => this.gato = product,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

  }
}
```

#### This is my detail component.html

```
<table>
  <tr><span class="visor-propiedad"> Nombre: </span><span class="visor-valor">{{gato.Nombre}}</span></tr>
  <tr><span class="visor-propiedad">Edad: </span><span class="visor-valor">{{gato.Edad}}</span></tr>
  <tr><span class="visor-propiedad">Raza: </span><span class="visor-valor">{{gato.Raza}}</span></tr>
  <tr><span class="visor-propiedad">Color: </span><span class="visor-valor">{{gato.Color}}</span></tr>
  <tr><span class="visor-propiedad">Vacunacion: </span><span class="visor-valor">{{gato.Vacunacion}}</span></tr>
  <tr><span class="detalle" [routerLink]="['/lafamilia', gato.Nombre]">Conóceme!</span></tr>
</table>
```

#### This is the error that shows on my browser console

```
 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./GatoDetalleComponent class GatoDetalleComponent - inline template:13:38 caused by: Cannot read property 'Nombre' of undefined
    Error: Error in ./GatoDetalleComponent class GatoDetalleComponent - inline template:13:38 caused by: Cannot read property 'Nombre' of undefined
```

#### Browser console does print the object I want. The problem arrises I believe is in interpolation.

```
gato.service.ts:27 Gato individual: {"Nombre":"Xiomara","Edad":"1","Raza":"Criolla","Color":"Café","Vacunacion":"Todas","Estado":"Esperando","Foto":"https://www.pexels.com/photo/grey-and-white-short-fur-cat-104827/"}
```

Comment: Have you tired: gato: IGato[] = [];

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
SO is a platform where you can get a good suggestion regarding your problems.  But for that, you need to be more specific about what you are asking?  what have you done so far?  Before asking please see the suggested SO question and take a look at them. Still, you did not find a solution then you can ask a question here.

Comment: Hi, Erica. At first, that wouldn't work because the observable that the getGato() returns is a single object, not an array, However, I tried to assign it a value that fits the interface, and it worked! I still don't know what is going on though. It seems, as Fahad stated below, the html was loading before the variable was assigned. But if that's the case, I dont get wht the ? operator wouldn't work. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your html code is executing before the value is assigned to `gato`. Add `?` befor `goto` inside interpolation like this:

```
<table>
<tr><span class="visor-propiedad"> Nombre: </span><span class="visor-valor">{{gato?.Nombre}}</span></tr>
<tr><span class="visor-propiedad">Edad: </span><span class="visor-valor">{{gato?.Edad}}</span></tr>
<tr><span class="visor-propiedad">Raza: </span><span class="visor-valor">{{gato?.Raza}}</span></tr>
<tr><span class="visor-propiedad">Color: </span><span class="visor-valor">{{gato?.Color}}</span></tr>
<tr><span class="visor-propiedad">Vacunacion: </span><span class="visor-valor">{{gato?.Vacunacion}}</span></tr>
<tr><span class="detalle" [routerLink]="['/lafamilia', gato?.Nombre]">Conóceme!</span></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, Fahad. I've tried this and still doesn't do it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Hi, again. As I commented above, you are actually right. When I assign gato a hard coded value , the page does work as aspected. That is, the page loads succesfully and inmediatly the hardcoded value is replaced by the one returned by the service. At least that seems to be the case. However, I still dont understand why the ? operator doesnt work. If you have any idea i would appreciate it. Thanks!